# Rewriting url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to access `movies.php?m=Bengali Audio` but in this format `movies/Bengali Audio` i write these `.htaccess` code but its showing File not found, where `movies.php?m=Bengali Audio`is working fine

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite for movies.php?m=Bengali Audio
RewriteRule ^movies/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+'')$ movies.php?m=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why do you have `''` in your pattern expression? Should be `^movies/([0-9a-z_-]+)$ movies.php?m=$1 [NC,L]` (also stripped out `A-Z` as you have the `NC` (no-case) flag set.

Comment: Of course, I omitted the check for whitespace - @anubhava is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex pattern to match spaces in movie name:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite for movies.php?m=Bengali Audio
RewriteRule ^movies/([^/]+)/?$ movies.php?m=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: its working, if i goto movies.php?m=Bengali Audio then all html design is changed, css not working

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: working : http://faltumusic.com/movies.php?m=Bengali%20Audio            Not working : http://faltumusic.com/movies/Bengali%20Audio